# Install list of packages

Tags: package, yum

I have a list of packages `mypacket.x86_64.rpm`https://pastebin.com/uiUDvaFi that I need to install for my project.

Is there a way to install them with only one command?
Btw, I'm using Centos, with yum downloader

Thanks for the help

Warok

Comment: Do you *really* want to install all those in one command? That's a big list and you may not know about any deps till install time. The short answer is yes you can just append the list to `yum install <package list separated with spaces>`

Comment: Or should I make a script for it? I don't know what's the best options

Comment: How many times do you expect to do this? if it's a one off then a long command line list will do - if you need to deploy over & over you may want to setup your own repo and use the yum group option to group things as you want then install with 1 or 2 commands